# Java library/API to help run windows commands

Tags: windows, api, java

Is there a Java library/API available to interact with Windows OS, like executing commands on the command prompt and returning the output back to the program?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `java.lang.Runtime.exec()` to do it, but read [this](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html) first.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [ProcessBuilder](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html), which is available starting from Java 1.5!

It has the nice ability to let you redirect the error stream which makes you only have to cope with one InputStream to read from.

Answer (score 0):

Good article here: [Runtime.exec()](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html) and the API is here: [link text](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html)