# How to run Windows commands in JAVA and return the result text as a string

Tags: java, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get output from a process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007425/get-output-from-a-process)
>   [Executing DOS commands from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031390/executing-dos-commands-from-java)

I am trying to run a cmd command from within a JAVA console program e.g.:

```
ver
```

and then return the output of the command into a string in JAVA e.g. output:

```
string result = "Windows NT 5.1"
```

Comment: You should have searched this before you ask this question. When I search for [run Windows commands in JAVA](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=run%20Windows%20commands%20in%20JAVA) in search of stackoverflow, I got below results... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935326/java-library-api-to-help-run-windows-commands http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031390/executing-dos-commands-from-java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7112259/how-to-execute-windows-commands-using-java-change-network-settings

Comment: This Link will help you: https://www.codepuran.com/java/execute-dos-command-java/

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use the following code for this

```
import java.io.*; 

    public class doscmd 
    { 
        public static void main(String args[]) 
        { 
            try 
            { 
                Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c dir"); 
                p.waitFor(); 
                BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream())
                ); 
                String line; 
                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
                { 
                    System.out.println(line);
                } 

            }
            catch(IOException e1) {e1.printStackTrace();} 
            catch(InterruptedException e2) {e2.printStackTrace();} 

            System.out.println("Done"); 
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Runtime exec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) in java to execute dos commands from java code.

Based on [Senthil's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5711150):

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C ver");
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()),8*1024);

BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

// read the output from the command

String s = null;
System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) 
System.out.println(s.replace("[","").replace("]",""));
```

Output = `Microsoft Windows Version 6.1.7600`

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like:

```
String line;
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec ("ver");
BufferedReader input =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
BufferedReader error =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

System.out.println("OUTPUT");
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null)
  System.out.println(line);
input.close();

System.out.println("ERROR");
while ((line = error.readLine()) != null)
  System.out.println(line);
error.close();
```

---

On comment of @RanRag, the main issue is Windows versus Unix/Mac.

- WINDOWS: exec("cmd /c ver");
- UNIX FLAVOUR: exec("ver");

Comment: You need to call exec with `Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C ver");`.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `java.lang.Runtime` or, better yet, [java.lang.Process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/)

[This](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.util/from-runtime.exec-to-processbuilder.html) might help you get started.