# execute sql in command line through sqlplus in java

Tags: java, sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have to execute an sql statement through SQLPLUS in JAVA without using the file
As we do it in command line in sqlplus. 
I need to make connection and execute the sql statement  in the same single line in Java

```
echo "show user;" | sqlplus USERNAME/PASSWORD as sysdba
```

I need to find the connection string for that.
How to do the same thing in Java??

Every suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: Its a different question totally. In this question my requirement is to create connection and run SQL statement in the same line rather than using a file in its syntax.

Comment: I don't see any difference. In both cases you (try to) run `sqlplus` from within Java. The connection is always done by `sqlplus`, never from within your Java program.

Answer (score 1):

There's an article [here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html?page=2) that describes better ways of calling the Runtime.getRuntime().exec()

The linked example may be a bit dated, but It still works.

The following code is based off [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963413/how-to-run-windows-commands-in-java-and-return-the-result-text-as-a-string)

```
import java.io.*;

public class doscmd
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try
        {
            String[] cmd = new String[3];


            cmd[0] = "cmd.exe" ;
            cmd[1] = "/C" ;
            cmd[2] = args[0];

            Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

            BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream())
            );

            BufferedReader error=new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream())
            );

            String line;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

            String errLine;
            while((errLine = error.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println(errLine);
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e1) {e1.printStackTrace();}


        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

Since I don't have sysdba access, I did try:

```
java doscmd "@echo show user; | sqlplus -L USERNAME/PASSWORD@DATABASE"
```

and it worked.

You should be able to do:

```
java doscmd "@echo show user; | sqlplus -L USERNAME/PASSWORD@DATABASE as sysdba"
```

I got

```
ERROR:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

Which leads me to believe it would work as well.